# Check the number range in the array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How can i Check the number range in the array value?
For example:

```
<?php
 $array = ['1'=>'100','2'=>'500','3'=>'1000','4'=>'2000'];

 function checkRange($int){
    /** Some codes that i need! **/
 }

 checkRange(361); // Should return 100
 checkRange(1723); // Should return 1000
 checkRange(842); // Should return 500
 checkRange(8046); // Should return 2000
```

Comment: Try replacing `/** Some codes that i need! **/` with `/** Some code that I tried! **/`

Comment: @NigelRen Actually, "my tried codes"  has bad writing And compare each array value!

Comment: And lose the keys in your array. They will get assigned automatically.

Comment: @NigelRen but then how are we supposed to trick people into doing our work for us?

Comment: @Amirm the point of StackOverflow is to help you by pointing out flaws in your code and helping you fix them, not to spoonfeed you finished solutions for copy/pasting. If you don't learn why your mistakes are mistakes you'll just keep making them.

Comment: @Amirm did my answer help you or is there any problems with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop the array backwards and compare if the number is larger than the array value.

```
$array = ['1'=>'100','2'=>'500','3'=>'1000','4'=>'2000'];
$n = 361;
rsort($array);

Foreach($array as $key => $val){
    If($n > $val){
        $res = $val;
        Break;
    }
}

Echo $val;
```

https://3v4l.org/mgiYR

Comment: This is great! Deleting my answer, yours is much cleaner.

Comment: Whats with the goofy capitalization ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat isn't that English? ;-) to be honest, it's my phone. It keeps capitalizing my code. And since the code works with capital letters I just don't bother changing it.